# Recommendation needed for a html line Graph to display device state

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a recommendation on the type of chart library to use for a HTML page that needs to show (iot) device states (on/off) across a timeline.. the graph needs to similar to a logic analyzer display. the Y axis will contains lines for each device separated by a certain distance and can toggle between a high and low state, while the X axis will be a timeline. I plan to display the state of up to 50 devices at a time.

I could use a traditional XY time series graph and assign a each device a number on the Y axis, an then make this number +1 whenever the device turns on and vice versa.. Although, this is possible, I am looking for any recommendation that would be more straight forward..

[image: device state time series]
<sub>(source: [utep.edu](http://www.ece.utep.edu/courses/web3376/Logic_Analyzer_files/droppedImage.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that graph using [Chart JS' Stepped Line Chart](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/stepped.html)

Comment: I understand that a stepped line chart is what I need.. but I also require to show the devices spreed across the Y axis while the line toggles between the on and off states.. Also,, on the Y axis I will require the device IDs rather than a particular number representing the Y axis value.. Any suggestion on how to implement this with the stepped line chart?

Comment: Please upvote this question as I have not received an answer to my question.. thanks